# Downloading 300,000+ rows from elasticsearch as a .csv file

Tags: javascript, database, elasticsearch, npm

Hello I have a website in nodejs, with a database in Elasticsearch. The index 'bigData*' has 366,844 rows, each row has 25 items, each item a different string, varying sizes with max being about 100 chars. I'm querying this index into a datatable I display on the page, I use scrolling to gradually load elements into the table and display it on the page. Datatables has a 'download all' option but it will only download what is loaded on the page. I am trying to implement a true 'download all' that will fetch all 366,844 rows, compile it into a file (csv), and then download it from the webpage.

I tried using scroll, like how its used to load the data, repeatedly calling my database for 10,000 rows. each time took 30 seconds, so 20 minutes in total.

I know something like this will probably take some time, I'm not expecting an instant solution. but my method also made chrome very laggy and slow, even almost crashing at one point. Does someone have a recommendation for downloading so much data? Potentially even a npm package or library for my project that can get the download ready in the background.

Thanks

Comment: create new endpoint.... in the endpoint fetch all, create csv and return as download.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things here:

1. When displaying so many rows, you may want to use [virtual scrolling](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/guides/virtual-scrolling/) which keeps the number of DOM elements (`<tr>`, `<td>`, ...) at a sane level and prevents scroll slowdown & jank. Are you using vanillaJS or some frameworks? There's a whole bunch of virtual scroll libs out there.
2. If 10,000 rows take 30 seconds, query in smaller batches (~200-500). By the time your users scroll down, another batch query will have already been resolved and renderable.
3. It sounds like you will *always* want to download all 366,844 rows -- no filters applied. If that's the case, on top of the above,  I'd do [S3 bucket csv 'dumps'](https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump) at reasonable intervals (could be the same file being overwritten w/ each backup) and link the latest one directly above the table in an `<a href="..." target="_blank" >`. That way, your site stays uncluttered and the client downloads the CSV at their own convenience.

Comment: sorry i should have mentioned that the data changes with querys, so the total number of elements in the table might be sorted by some filters, such as 'show only results where category1 is 'item1' or 'item2'' , this example query would make the total number of products = 223,232 so i would need to download all of those rows. im going to look into creating the csb/xml file on backend and sending an email to user once its done

Comment: go w/ it. The frontend version is going to be slow...